# SQL Server regex alternation

Tags: sql-server, regex

What would be the proper format for the following regular expression in SQL Server?

```
select top 100 * 
from posts
where tags like '(c++)|(performance)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not support formal regex, so you will have to use `LIKE` here:

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM posts
WHERE tags LIKE '%c++%' OR tags LIKE '%performance%';
```

Note: If the `tags` column really stores one tag per record, then just use equality checks:

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM posts
WHERE tags IN ('%c++', 'performance');
```

Comment: ah that's so strange, for everything else that it does support, to think of something so basic...

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 SQL Server's `LIKE` operator is enhanced and does have some very basic regex capability, and there is a `PATINDEX` function with some regex support.  If you show your actual data, maybe the above query can be improved upon.